# how to solve undefined local variable or method `has_mailbox'?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, private-messaging

I am following [this tutorial](https://github.com/fajrif/has_mailbox) to add messaging functionality between the users in my rails app, but got an error in my `User` model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_mailbox
end
```

This gives me the following error:

```
undefined local variable or method `has_mailbox' for #<Class:0xb60f6f84>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you run the bundle command after adding `gem "has_mailbox"` to your Gemfile? Did you generate and run the migration?

Comment: yes I did n also run the migration,but i'm not able to understand how to add has_mailbox method in user model?

Comment: did you restart your server ?

Comment: @Said Kaldybaev: yeah i restart my server,but can you tell me how to write that has_mailbox method? I downloaded this tutorial & it include module HasMailbox in has_mailbox.rb file that i have to include in user model?

Comment: you don't need to create this method, i's already provided to you by gem

Comment: @Said Kaldybaev: But sir When i try to send message from 1 user to another through send_message like e.g. @user1.send_message("Hi Subject","Hi Body !!!",@user2) on console then it give me error like  "undefined method `send_message' for #<User:0xb6e874a0>"
and one more thing is that how the instance variable can call the send_message method until we define it in user model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've checked this gem, try to run

```
rails g has_mailbox:install
```

when you install any gem in rails app, the good idea is to check generators available

```
rails g //list of available generators
```

Comment: It only generates the view sir, but i'm still getting an error in send_message method like undefined send_message method:<User:"cxvcx21344"> when i write like this @user1.send_message("Hi Subject","Hi Body !!!",@user2)

Comment: i've just installed this gem, and did the same in that tutorial, it worked, please exit from your current terminal session and enter again

Comment: can u send me your tutorial on my email:patel.donika89.sndt@gmail.com

Comment: I check my mail id i didn't get any mail from you or any reply on stackoverflow! :(

Comment: Said Kaldybaev :  can u post d steps here that u u followed

Comment: @Donika Patel, i was busy at that time. now you can check your mail

Comment: Said Kaldybaev: k! thank you so much! but there is one problem in my project. Actually I already created a message model for my project and now the problem is that I did associatiion with it with my two model n did lot of work on that then now how i make changes in has_mailbox gem to work with different model name?